# Can I add Tasker integration to my Cordova app?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, tasker

Is there a way for me to add Tasker integration to a Cordova App? I want Tasker to be able to open the app and trigger a JS function, and I want the app to trigger a Tasker profile.